# Pygame game acting differently at differnet framerates

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get an enemy character to shoot a bullet and then the next bullet with be 40 degrees over clockwise and shoot at the same speed, but for some reason at higher framerates it doesn't come out symmetrical in fact the higher the frames the less symmetrical it is. My code for this looks like this. When it's ready to fire it does this

```
if self.kind == "RapidSpinner":
    self.attackY =  math.cos(self.angle) * 150
    self.attackX = math.sin(self.angle) * 150      
    self.angle -= math.pi / 9
```

Where "RapidSpinner" refers to the type of enemy, self.angle is changed for the next call to shoot and self.attackX and Y refer to the movement of the bullets, self.attackX and Y become translated to the general self.dy and dx then the bullets movement is define like this.

```
 self.rect.y += self.dy * dt
 self.rect.x += self.dx * dt
```

and dt is defined like this

```
dt = clock.tick(30)
dt = dt/1000.
```

What's wrong with my code that's making these weird patterns at high framerate instead of being a perfect spiral? By high I mean anything over 15 looks odd and even at 15 it's not perfect.

Comment: Where does `dt` come from? Is it possibly something like `1000 // framerate`, which means you get more rounding error the higher `framerate` gets? Or, are values rounded to integers somewhere?

Comment: From what I've read on pygame when you say dt = clock.tick(30) it takes a "microsleep" to make the framerate whatever the parameter is for clock.tick() so in this case it limits the framerate to 30 and allows for things to be based off this measure of time that can vary from computer to computer and still end with moving the correct amount even at higher or lower framerates. I'm not sure if that answered the question but dt essentially is just the time between runs of the while loop that the entire game is in. And to be more precise I have clock = pygame.time.Clock() then dt = clock.tick(30)

Comment: OK, first, is this Python 2.x or 3.x? Because in 2.x, `30 / 1000` is `0`, not `.03`.

Comment: Meanwhile, using `clock.tick(fps)/1000` instead of `1./fps` means that if the game lags too badly to keep up, everything starts teleporting around instead of slowing down to match the game. Is that intentional? I'm not sure it's related to your problem or not, but… are you actually keeping up with the requested framerate, or is it actually getting worse the more you fall behind, rather than (directly) getting worse the higher the requested framerate?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. It is (1000.) not (1000), but the game is achieving these higher framerates. I can tell because the game runs smoother and faster than before until about clock.tick(100). It is python 2.x though.

Answer (score 0):

`self.angle` is changed by a fixed amount per frame, not dependent on the number of frames per second:

```
self.angle -= math.pi / 9
```

But `dt` (and therefore `dx` and `dy`) is changed by a fixed amount per second:

```
dt = clock.tick(30)
dt = dt/1000.
```

If your frame rate is exactly 30fps, perfect to the nanosecond, this won't make any difference, and you'll get a perfect digitized spiral.*

But if your frame rate varies, even if it sticks pretty close to an average of 30fps, you're going to move longer segments at some angles than at others, which is going to give you a weird, imperfect spiral.

For example, let's say you rotate π/9 then move 35 units, then rotate π/9 and move 31 units, then rotate π/9 and move 34 units, etc. That's not going to look the same as moving 33.3+ units each time. And the higher the framerate gets, the more variation you're going to get.

Even with a small variation,** you can see that the left spiral is already visible mutated:
[image]

To fix this, you can either:

- Assume each tick takes exactly 1/fps by using a constant `dt = 1/30.` instead of `dt = clock.tick(30)/1000`.
- Use the actual value of each tick by multiplying the `angle` update by something based on the result of `clock.tick`, the same way you do for `dt`.

The former is a bit simpler, but the real reason to choose between them is what you want to happen if the computer can't keep up with the desired framerate (or if, say, the computer goes to sleep without pausing your game). The first solution means that everything will slow down as the game lags; the second means that everything will keep running at full speed but will look to the user like it's "teleporting" around.

---

<sub>* Which, of course, isn't the same thing as an actual perfect spiral, but I'm assuming you already know that.</sub>

<sub>** I wrote out 100 ticks at 30fps while doing absolutely nothing, then used a triangular distribution between that min and max with 30fps as the mode, then simulated the output with the `turtle` module.</sub>

Comment: This is a good answer, I think it can be modified to answer what I'm looking for. I don't think I was clear enough in the explanation of the problem. So the bullets aren't moving in a circle themselves. What I would like is to have an apparent spiral formed by shooting a bullet out of a stationary object then shooting another at pi/9 difference to the other one. Essentially it should look like this but only one row. http://gaminghell.co.uk/images/pcbs3amm11.png What I end up with though is consistent and correct angles but only consistent speeds that aren't correct. That is some move too slow.

Comment: Also it might be good to know that it doesn't happen every frame but it is on a cooldown that gets reset after it fires and counts down till the next time it can fire. Although I'm not sure that would affect anything.

Comment: Note that the bullets with always move in straight lines and that that is intentional.

Comment: @user3697905: OK, I now understand what you're saying. I _think_ the problem could still be the one that I suggested, but I'm not positive. It sounds like you understand both my answer and your problem well enough to let me know if this is a solution or not. If it's in the right direction, and enough to get you started, but not an actual solution, you can always write and accept your own answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the problem unfortunately. I tried making dt fixed and didn't get anywhere and then i tried making using self.angle -= math.pi/9 * dt * 25 25 as just an arbitrary scalar. This is what I get when I do self.angle -= math.pi/9 * dt * 25 :http://puu.sh/cLA0G/e149ae21bd.jpg This is what I get when I do a fixed dt, 30/1000. in this case :http://puu.sh/cLAcu/a1351fdf25.jpg

Comment: @user3697905: Yeah, hard to be positive, but they both look screwed up in the same way… Oh well, hopefully someone else will look, or something will come to me later…

Comment: Is there any way that I could talk to you more about this situation I have here, because this is a project for school but also I'm new to game coding and pygame and I can't seem to understand what could possibly be the problem. I'm feeling a little bit desperate haha, I really would like for this to work. Thanks!